# Convert existing Free app into Inapppurchase

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

Currently our app has existing users, who are accessing the data which have been given to them **free of cost**. Initially when we tried to push this app to app store,, Apple didn't allowed us because of the paid subscriptions on our website, however, after detailed discussion with the Apple support and providing the details about the free availability of content, we were able to launch the app to App Store

> > my question is  now we are planning to introduce the **subscriptions** (in app purchase) in App and would have paid content in APP. Having said that, if we sell the free content as paid now, would that have any impact on existing users in terms of **30% share**?

We have asked this question to apple support but still waiting for their response, but we need to update our client.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but if you use an auto renewing subscription in app purchase, Apple keeps 30% of the subscription price. If the user is still subscribing after one year then Apple's percentage drops to 15% https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

Comment: we have already app live on app store and this app is totally free. Now we would like to add one time subscription inside the app. but old user will use app for free and new use pay subscription before using the app , is apple charge its commission for old user or not. its clear that apple will charge commission for new user.

Comment: It depends on how you provide the content to "old users". If the old users don't make an in app purchase then there is nothing for Apple to take a fee from.  So, for example, if you check the receipt and unlock the content based on the original purchase version, they don't need to purchase a subscription.